# Optimizing a Postgres query with a large array inside IN clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

guys

I have the following query:

```
WITH skuids as (
SELECT coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId") as "SKUId"
FROM public.processedorder po
INNER JOIN public.processedorder_item poi ON po."OrderId" = poi."OrderId"
LEFT JOIN public.processedorder_item_composite_child picc on picc."OrderItemId" = poi."OrderItemId"
WHERE po."ProcessedDate" >= '2021-03-10' AND po."ProcessedDate" <= '2021-03-20'
GROUP BY coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId")
),
monthcoderange as (
    SELECT cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer) as "timestamp"
    FROM generate_series('2021-03-10'::date, '2021-03-20'::date, interval '1 day') s
    GROUP BY  cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) as "daysoutofstock", s."SKUId"
    FROM (
        SELECT sh."SKUId", TO_DATE(sh."MonthCode" || RIGHT('0' || a.nr::varchar(2),2),'YYYYMMDD') as "Date"
        FROM public.stockhistory sh, unnest("EndOfDayLevel") WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr)
        WHERE "SKUId" IN (select "SKUId" from skuids)
          AND "MonthCode" IN (select "timestamp" from monthcoderange)
        GROUP BY a.nr, sh."SKUId", sh."MonthCode"
        HAVING SUM(a.elem) = 0
    ) as s
    WHERE "Date" >= '2021-03-10' AND "Date" <= '2021-03-20'
    GROUP BY s."SKUId";
```

where I need to calculate **days out of stock** for my products with some range of time.

In prod env it takes a lot of time (more than 30 seconds on average) because of the large array inside **IN** statement, my **skuids's** array length on average 2000-4000 elements. What I have tried before?

1. Use **JOIN** instead of **WHERE IN**

```
WITH skuids as (
SELECT coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId") as "SKUId"
FROM public.processedorder po
INNER JOIN public.processedorder_item poi ON po."OrderId" = poi."OrderId"
LEFT JOIN public.processedorder_item_composite_child picc on picc."OrderItemId" = poi."OrderItemId"
WHERE po."ProcessedDate" >= '2021-04-10' AND po."ProcessedDate" <= '2021-04-20'
GROUP BY coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId")
),
monthcoderange as (
    SELECT cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer) as "timestamp"
    FROM generate_series('2021-04-10'::date, '2021-04-20'::date, interval '1 day') s
    GROUP BY  cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) as "daysoutofstock", s."SKUId"
    FROM (
        SELECT sh."SKUId", TO_DATE(sh."MonthCode" || RIGHT('0' || a.nr::varchar(2),2),'YYYYMMDD') as "Date"
        FROM public.stockhistory sh
        JOIN skuids ex(skuId) ON sh."SKUId" = ex.skuId, unnest("EndOfDayLevel") WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr)
        WHERE sh."MonthCode" IN (select "timestamp" from monthcoderange)
        GROUP BY a.nr, sh."SKUId", sh."MonthCode"
        HAVING SUM(a.elem) = 0
    ) as s
    WHERE "Date" >= '2021-04-10' AND "Date" <= '2021-04-20'
    GROUP BY s."SKUId";
```

but seems like it takes the same time.

2. Use **ANY** instead of **IN**

```
WITH skuids as (
SELECT coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId") as "SKUId"
FROM public.processedorder po
INNER JOIN public.processedorder_item poi ON po."OrderId" = poi."OrderId"
LEFT JOIN public.processedorder_item_composite_child picc on picc."OrderItemId" = poi."OrderItemId"
WHERE po."ProcessedDate" >= '2021-03-10' AND po."ProcessedDate" <= '2021-03-20'
GROUP BY coalesce(picc."SKUId",poi."SKUId")
), 
monthcoderange as (
    SELECT cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer) as "timestamp"
    FROM generate_series('2021-03-10'::date, '2021-03-20'::date, interval '1 day') s
    GROUP BY  cast(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM') as integer)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) as "daysoutofstock", s."SKUId"
    FROM (
        SELECT sh."SKUId", TO_DATE(sh."MonthCode" || RIGHT('0' || a.nr::varchar(2),2),'YYYYMMDD') as "Date"
        FROM public.stockhistory sh, unnest("EndOfDayLevel") WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr)
        WHERE "SKUId" = ANY (select "SKUId" from skuids)
          AND "MonthCode" IN (select "timestamp" from monthcoderange)
        GROUP BY a.nr, sh."SKUId", sh."MonthCode"
        HAVING SUM(a.elem) = 0
    ) as s
    WHERE "Date" >= '2021-03-10' AND "Date" <= '2021-03-20'
    GROUP BY s."SKUId";
```

I have the following indexes in **public.stockhistory**:

```
create table stockhistory
(
    "SKUId"           integer          not null,
    "LocationId"      integer          not null,
    "MonthCode"       integer          not null,
    "EndOfDayLevel"   integer[]        not null,
    "EndOfDayValue"   numeric(18, 6)[] not null,
    "DaysInMonth"     integer          not null,
    "EndOfMonthLevel" integer,
    "EndOfMonthValue" numeric(18, 6),
    lastday           integer,
    constraint stockhistory_pkey
        primary key ("SKUId", "LocationId", "MonthCode")
)
    with (fillfactor = 50);

alter table stockhistory
    owner to user_psql01;

create index ix_stockhistory_month
    on stockhistory ("MonthCode" desc);

create index ix_stockhistory_monthcode_sku_location
    on stockhistory ("SKUId" asc, "LocationId" asc, "MonthCode" desc);

create index ix_stockhistory_month_location
    on stockhistory ("MonthCode" desc, "LocationId" asc);
```

Here is query plan of this query:

```
[
    {
      "Plan": {
        "Node Type": "Aggregate",
        "Strategy": "Hashed",
        "Partial Mode": "Simple",
        "Parallel Aware": false,
        "Startup Cost": 137310.29,
        "Total Cost": 137312.29,
        "Plan Rows": 200,
        "Plan Width": 12,
        "Actual Startup Time": 31948.627,
        "Actual Total Time": 31948.629,
        "Actual Rows": 1,
        "Actual Loops": 1,
        "Group Key": ["sh.\"SKUId\""],
        "Plans": [
          {
            "Node Type": "Group",
            "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
            "Subplan Name": "CTE skuids",
            "Parallel Aware": false,
            "Startup Cost": 136826.48,
            "Total Cost": 136826.49,
            "Plan Rows": 1,
            "Plan Width": 4,
            "Actual Startup Time": 398.795,
            "Actual Total Time": 416.706,
            "Actual Rows": 2579,
            "Actual Loops": 1,
            "Group Key": ["(COALESCE(picc.\"SKUId\", poi.\"SKUId\"))"],
            "Plans": [
              {
                "Node Type": "Sort",
                "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                "Parallel Aware": false,
                "Startup Cost": 136826.48,
                "Total Cost": 136826.49,
                "Plan Rows": 1,
                "Plan Width": 4,
                "Actual Startup Time": 398.792,
                "Actual Total Time": 406.434,
                "Actual Rows": 7864,
                "Actual Loops": 1,
                "Sort Key": ["(COALESCE(picc.\"SKUId\", poi.\"SKUId\"))"],
                "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                "Sort Space Used": 561,
                "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
                "Plans": [
                  {
                    "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                    "Parallel Aware": false,
                    "Join Type": "Left",
                    "Startup Cost": 1000.85,
                    "Total Cost": 136826.47,
                    "Plan Rows": 1,
                    "Plan Width": 4,
                    "Actual Startup Time": 284.037,
                    "Actual Total Time": 391.343,
                    "Actual Rows": 7864,
                    "Actual Loops": 1,
                    "Inner Unique": false,
                    "Plans": [
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                        "Parallel Aware": false,
                        "Join Type": "Inner",
                        "Startup Cost": 1000.43,
                        "Total Cost": 136825.98,
                        "Plan Rows": 1,
                        "Plan Width": 8,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 284.026,
                        "Actual Total Time": 358.751,
                        "Actual Rows": 7864,
                        "Actual Loops": 1,
                        "Inner Unique": false,
                        "Plans": [
                          {
                            "Node Type": "Gather",
                            "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                            "Parallel Aware": false,
                            "Startup Cost": 1000.00,
                            "Total Cost": 136817.52,
                            "Plan Rows": 1,
                            "Plan Width": 4,
                            "Actual Startup Time": 283.983,
                            "Actual Total Time": 310.144,
                            "Actual Rows": 6646,
                            "Actual Loops": 1,
                            "Workers Planned": 2,
                            "Workers Launched": 2,
                            "Single Copy": false,
                            "Plans": [
                              {
                                "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                                "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                                "Parallel Aware": true,
                                "Relation Name": "processedorder",
                                "Alias": "po",
                                "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                                "Total Cost": 135817.42,
                                "Plan Rows": 1,
                                "Plan Width": 4,
                                "Actual Startup Time": 284.489,
                                "Actual Total Time": 297.558,
                                "Actual Rows": 2215,
                                "Actual Loops": 3,
                                "Filter": "((\"ProcessedDate\" >= '2021-04-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (\"ProcessedDate\" <= '2021-04-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))",
                                "Rows Removed by Filter": 615696
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                            "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                            "Parallel Aware": false,
                            "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                            "Index Name": "ix_processedorder_item_orderid",
                            "Relation Name": "processedorder_item",
                            "Alias": "poi",
                            "Startup Cost": 0.43,
                            "Total Cost": 8.45,
                            "Plan Rows": 1,
                            "Plan Width": 12,
                            "Actual Startup Time": 0.003,
                            "Actual Total Time": 0.004,
                            "Actual Rows": 1,
                            "Actual Loops": 6646,
                            "Index Cond": "(\"OrderId\" = po.\"OrderId\")",
                            "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                        "Parallel Aware": false,
                        "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                        "Index Name": "ix_processedorder_item_compositechild_orderitemid",
                        "Relation Name": "processedorder_item_composite_child",
                        "Alias": "picc",
                        "Startup Cost": 0.42,
                        "Total Cost": 0.48,
                        "Plan Rows": 1,
                        "Plan Width": 8,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 0.002,
                        "Actual Total Time": 0.002,
                        "Actual Rows": 0,
                        "Actual Loops": 7864,
                        "Index Cond": "(\"OrderItemId\" = poi.\"OrderItemId\")",
                        "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Node Type": "Aggregate",
            "Strategy": "Hashed",
            "Partial Mode": "Simple",
            "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
            "Subplan Name": "CTE monthcoderange",
            "Parallel Aware": false,
            "Startup Cost": 20.01,
            "Total Cost": 23.51,
            "Plan Rows": 200,
            "Plan Width": 4,
            "Actual Startup Time": 0.052,
            "Actual Total Time": 0.054,
            "Actual Rows": 1,
            "Actual Loops": 1,
            "Group Key": ["(to_char(s.s, 'YYYYMM'::text))::integer"],
            "Plans": [
              {
                "Node Type": "Function Scan",
                "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                "Parallel Aware": false,
                "Function Name": "generate_series",
                "Alias": "s",
                "Startup Cost": 0.01,
                "Total Cost": 17.51,
                "Plan Rows": 1000,
                "Plan Width": 4,
                "Actual Startup Time": 0.023,
                "Actual Total Time": 0.037,
                "Actual Rows": 11,
                "Actual Loops": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Node Type": "Aggregate",
            "Strategy": "Hashed",
            "Partial Mode": "Simple",
            "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
            "Parallel Aware": false,
            "Startup Cost": 448.35,
            "Total Cost": 453.13,
            "Plan Rows": 478,
            "Plan Width": 20,
            "Actual Startup Time": 31944.293,
            "Actual Total Time": 31948.609,
            "Actual Rows": 11,
            "Actual Loops": 1,
            "Group Key": ["a.nr", "sh.\"SKUId\"", "sh.\"MonthCode\""],
            "Filter": "(sum(a.elem) = 0)",
            "Rows Removed by Filter": 28347,
            "Plans": [
              {
                "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                "Parallel Aware": false,
                "Join Type": "Inner",
                "Startup Cost": 7.07,
                "Total Cost": 443.57,
                "Plan Rows": 478,
                "Plan Width": 20,
                "Actual Startup Time": 399.621,
                "Actual Total Time": 31902.876,
                "Actual Rows": 28358,
                "Actual Loops": 1,
                "Inner Unique": false,
                "Plans": [
                  {
                    "Node Type": "Hash Join",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                    "Parallel Aware": false,
                    "Join Type": "Semi",
                    "Startup Cost": 7.06,
                    "Total Cost": 180.84,
                    "Plan Rows": 43,
                    "Plan Width": 150,
                    "Actual Startup Time": 399.595,
                    "Actual Total Time": 31726.264,
                    "Actual Rows": 2578,
                    "Actual Loops": 1,
                    "Inner Unique": false,
                    "Hash Cond": "(sh.\"MonthCode\" = monthcoderange.\"timestamp\")",
                    "Plans": [
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                        "Parallel Aware": false,
                        "Join Type": "Inner",
                        "Startup Cost": 0.56,
                        "Total Cost": 172.72,
                        "Plan Rows": 43,
                        "Plan Width": 150,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 399.508,
                        "Actual Total Time": 31644.783,
                        "Actual Rows": 81119,
                        "Actual Loops": 1,
                        "Inner Unique": false,
                        "Plans": [
                          {
                            "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
                            "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                            "Parallel Aware": false,
                            "CTE Name": "skuids",
                            "Alias": "ex",
                            "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                            "Total Cost": 0.02,
                            "Plan Rows": 1,
                            "Plan Width": 4,
                            "Actual Startup Time": 398.799,
                            "Actual Total Time": 423.187,
                            "Actual Rows": 2579,
                            "Actual Loops": 1
                          },
                          {
                            "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                            "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                            "Parallel Aware": false,
                            "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                            "Index Name": "ix_stockhistory_monthcode_sku_location",
                            "Relation Name": "stockhistory",
                            "Alias": "sh",
                            "Startup Cost": 0.56,
                            "Total Cost": 172.27,
                            "Plan Rows": 43,
                            "Plan Width": 150,
                            "Actual Startup Time": 0.955,
                            "Actual Total Time": 12.050,
                            "Actual Rows": 31,
                            "Actual Loops": 2579,
                            "Index Cond": "(\"SKUId\" = ex.skuid)",
                            "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Hash",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                        "Parallel Aware": false,
                        "Startup Cost": 4.00,
                        "Total Cost": 4.00,
                        "Plan Rows": 200,
                        "Plan Width": 4,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 0.061,
                        "Actual Total Time": 0.061,
                        "Actual Rows": 1,
                        "Actual Loops": 1,
                        "Hash Buckets": 1024,
                        "Original Hash Buckets": 1024,
                        "Hash Batches": 1,
                        "Original Hash Batches": 1,
                        "Peak Memory Usage": 9,
                        "Plans": [
                          {
                            "Node Type": "CTE Scan",
                            "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                            "Parallel Aware": false,
                            "CTE Name": "monthcoderange",
                            "Alias": "monthcoderange",
                            "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                            "Total Cost": 4.00,
                            "Plan Rows": 200,
                            "Plan Width": 4,
                            "Actual Startup Time": 0.055,
                            "Actual Total Time": 0.058,
                            "Actual Rows": 1,
                            "Actual Loops": 1
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Node Type": "Function Scan",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                    "Parallel Aware": false,
                    "Function Name": "unnest",
                    "Alias": "a",
                    "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                    "Total Cost": 6.00,
                    "Plan Rows": 11,
                    "Plan Width": 12,
                    "Actual Startup Time": 0.019,
                    "Actual Total Time": 0.049,
                    "Actual Rows": 11,
                    "Actual Loops": 2578,
                    "Filter": "((to_date(((sh.\"MonthCode\")::text || \"right\"(('0'::text || ((nr)::character varying(2))::text), 2)), 'YYYYMMDD'::text) >= '2021-04-10'::date) AND (to_date(((sh.\"MonthCode\")::text || \"right\"(('0'::text || ((nr)::character varying(2))::text), 2)), 'YYYYMMDD'::text) <= '2021-04-20'::date))",
                    "Rows Removed by Filter": 19
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "Planning Time": 2.565,
      "Triggers": [
      ],
      "Execution Time": 31949.116
    }
  ]
```

Here is the most problem part of it in my view:

```
{
   "Node Type": "Index Scan",
   "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
   "Parallel Aware": false,
   "Scan Direction": "Forward",
   "Index Name": "ix_stockhistory_monthcode_sku_location",
   "Relation Name": "stockhistory",
   "Alias": "sh",
   "Startup Cost": 0.56,
   "Total Cost": 172.27,
   "Plan Rows": 43,
   "Plan Width": 150,
   "Actual Startup Time": 0.955,
   "Actual Total Time": 12.050,
   "Actual Rows": 31,
   "Actual Loops": 2579,
   "Index Cond": "(\"SKUId\" = ex.skuid)",
   "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0
}
```

I'm thinking about creating temp table with **skuids**, index this table and **JOIN** it like in the 2 query, but may be I have missed something here. May be I need to have a separate index in **public.stockhistory** for **"SKUId"**

Thanks!

Comment: Your first 2 code blocks omit the `WITH skuids AS` line at the top, making it hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. Updated @j_random_hacker

Comment: Is it any different if you join to both skuids and monthcoderange?

Comment: @Jeremy the same, I figured out the main issue because of the 
unnest("EndOfDayLevel") WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr).
EndOfDayLevel - array, that contains count of the product of each day for specific month. I need to expand this array to calculate days out of stock. But because of this function the join itself takes a lot of time.

Comment: Have you VACUUM ANALYZED everything?  The estimated number of skuids returned by the CTE is way off.

Comment: The JSON format if good for machines to read, but horrible for people to read.  Please show plans in text format.

Comment: @jjanes 
I don't know why, buy when i'm using 
WHERE "SKUId" = ANY (ARRAY(select "SKUId" from skuids)) it works fast.